# Check if a particular string is in a file bash

Tags: bash, search, string, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I want to write a script to check for duplicates
For example: I have a text file with information in the format of /etc/passwd

```
alice:x:1008:555:William Williams:/home/bill:/bin/bash
bob:x:1018:588:Bobs Boos:/home/bob:/bin/bash
bob:x:1019:528:Robt Ross:/home/bob:/bin/bash
james:x:1012:518:Tilly James:/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

I want to simply check if there are duplicate users and if there are, output the line to standard error. So in the example above since bob appears twice my output would simply generate something like:

```
Error duplicate user
bob:x:1018:588:Bobs Boos:/home/bob:/bin/bash
bob:x:1019:528:Robt Ross:/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

Right now I have a while loop that reads each line and stores each piece of information in a variable using awk -F that is delimited with ":". After storing my username I am not too sure on the best approach to check to see if it already exists.

Some parts of my code:

```
while read line; do
        echo $line
        user=`echo $line | awk -F : '{print $1}'`
        match=`grep $user $1`($1 is the txtfile)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "Unique user"
        else
                echo "Not unique user"
                then somehow grep those lines and output it
        fi
done
```

The matching does not produce the right results
Suggestions?

Comment: `grep` only returns a non-zero exit code when there's *no* match.

Answer (score 4):

instead of re-inventing the wheel, use the following tools:

- `cut` to extract first field
- `sort` and `uniq` to keep duplicated lines only.

  ```
  cut -d : -f 1 | sort | uniq -d | while read i ; do
                                     echo "error: duplicate user $i"
                                   done
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `awk` to me:

```
% awk -F':' '
/:/ {
    count[$1] += 1
}

END {
    for (user in count) {
        if (count[user] > 1) {
            print user " appears in the file " count[user] " times."
        }
    }
}
' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

A perl-proposal:

```
perl -F: -lanE 'push @{$h{$F[0]}},$_; END{for $k (keys %h){if(@{$h{$k}}>1){say "Error";say for @{$h{$k}}}}}' file
```